# Filing Date of abandoned patent applications:effective filing date?

Tags: filing-date, effective-filing-date

To determine the earliest effective filing date of a US patent application: Can the filing date of an **abandoned** US patent application be the effective filing date? Example US 9,220,781 B2 (application no 14/799,211):
[https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/#!/applications/14799211/continuity][1]

Filing or 371 (c) date
07/14/2015

14/799,211  is a Continuation of    14/558,182  12/1/2014   Patented    9,114,166

14/558,182  is a Continuation of    14/453,490  8/5/2014    Patented    8,916,158

14/453,490  is a Continuation of    14/322,581  7/1/2014    Patented    8,911,741

14/322,581  is a Continuation of    14/091,938  11/26/2013  Patented    8,795,670

14/091,938  is a Continuation of    13/471,820  5/14/2012   Patented    8,932,591

13/471,820  is a Continuation of    10/525,292  10/26/2005  -           8,216,583

10/525,292  is a National Stage Entry of    PCT/IB2003/004502   8/14/2003   -   -   -

PCT/IB2003/004502   is a Continuation of    10/222,140  **8/15/2002**   **Abandoned**   -

*Is 8/15/2002 of US patent application 10/222,140 the effective filing date?*

Answer (score 2):

As long as there is continuity of applications with overlapping pendency the outcome of the applications doesn't matter.

Comment: It seems you've used the phrase "doesn't matter" twice in the same sentence. Perhaps you could edit for clarity?

Comment: Despite the list of continuations the 371 (c) date is 07-14-2015. Should I assume the patent is in force for 20 years from that date?

Comment: No - 20 years from the PCT filing date. From USPTO "A patent granted on an international application filed on or after June 8, 1995 and which enters the national stage under 35 U.S.C. 371 will have a term which ends twenty years from the filing date of the international application. A continuation or a continuation-in-part application claiming benefit under 35 U.S.C. 365(c) of an international application filed under 35 U.S.C. 363 designating the United States will have a term which ends twenty years from the filing date of the parent international application. "